# SQL Query - combine 2 rows into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query below (view) in SQL Server.  The query produces a result set that is needed to populate a grid.  However, a new requirement has come up where the users would like to see data on one row in our app.  The tblTasks table can produce 1 or 2 rows.  The issue becomes when they're is two rows that have the same job_number but different fldProjectContextId (1 or 31).  I need to get the MechApprovalOut and ElecApprovalOut columns on one row instead of two.

I've tried restructuring the query using CTE and over partition and haven't been able to get the necessary results I need.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
       CAST(dbo.Job_Control.job_number AS int) AS Job_Number,
       dbo.tblTasks.fldSalesOrder, dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldTaskCategoryName,
       dbo.Job_Control.Dwg_Sent, dbo.Job_Control.Approval_done,
       dbo.Job_Control.fldElecDwgSent, dbo.Job_Control.fldElecApprovalDone,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Job_Control.Dwg_Sent, GETDATE()) > 14
             AND dbo.Job_Control.Approval_done IS NULL
             AND dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextID = 1
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS MechApprovalOut,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Job_Control.fldElecDwgSent, GETDATE()) > 14
             AND dbo.Job_Control.fldElecApprovalDone IS NULL
             AND dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextID = 31
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS ElecApprovalOut,
       dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextName,
       dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextId, dbo.Job_Control.Drawing_Info,
       dbo.Job_Control.fldElectricalAppDwg
  FROM dbo.tblTaskCategories
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblTasks
          ON dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldTaskCategoryId = dbo.tblTasks.fldTaskCategoryId
       INNER JOIN dbo.Job_Control
          ON dbo.tblTasks.fldSalesOrder = dbo.Job_Control.job_number
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjectContext
          ON dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldProjectContextId = dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextId
 WHERE (dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldTaskCategoryName = N'Approval'
       OR dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldTaskCategoryName = N'Re-Approval')
   AND (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Job_Control.Dwg_Sent, GETDATE()) > 14
              AND dbo.Job_Control.Approval_done IS NULL
              AND dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextID = 1
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
          END = 1)
    OR (dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldTaskCategoryName = N'Approval'
       OR dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldTaskCategoryName = N'Re-Approval')
   AND (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Job_Control.fldElecDwgSent, GETDATE()) > 14
              AND dbo.Job_Control.fldElecApprovalDone IS NULL
              AND dbo.tblProjectContext.fldProjectContextID = 31
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END = 1)
 ORDER BY dbo.Job_Control.job_number, dbo.tblTaskCategories.fldProjectContextId
```

The above query gives me the following result set:
[image]

I've created a work around via code (which I don't like but it works for now) where i've used code to populate a "temp" table the way i need it to display the data, that is, one record if duplicate job numbers to get the MechApprovalOut and ElecApprovalOut columns on one row (see first record in following screen shot).

Example:
[image]

With the desired result set and one row per job_number, this is how the form looks with the data and how I am using the result set.

[image]

Any help restructuring my query to combine duplicate rows with the same job number where MechApprovalOut and ElecApproval out columns are on one row is greatly appreciated! I'd much prefer to use a view on SQL then code in the app to populate a temp table.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: What did your attempt with CTE and over partition look like?  Because that's how I would solve this.

Comment: Maybe you are already handling it in your where clause, but how do you handle that `fldTaskCategoryID` is also different?

Comment: @TabAlleman, the over partition gave me one row as I used rank, but I could not figure out how to combine the MechApprovalsOut or ElecApprovalsOut columns into the returned row.  And the CTE I could not get to give me a single row. Any help with suggestions on either of these approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired logic for deciding which ApprovalsOut columns to use when there is more than one row?

Comment: @Rhumborl, my apologies but I'm a bit confused by your question on the fldTaskCategoryID. Are you suggesting using that in some way in the where clause (it's currently not)?  I'm currently only using it to join the tblTasks and tblTaskCategories tables.

Comment: @TabAlleman, the projectcontextId of 1 = sales and 31 = sales; 1 for Mechanical department and 31 for electrical department.  The task table stores "tasks" and the projectcontextId determines which project department.  In the last screen shot of the form, there are buttons to "View Work Package".  Since there is a mechanical and electrical task record whose approval out is greater than 14 days, you can view each work package to review the details and take action.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is LEFT JOIN the main table to itself at the beginning of the query, matching on Job Number and Sales Order, such that the left side of the join is only looking at `Approval` task categories and the right side of the join is only looking at `Re-Approval` task categories. Then I would make extensive use of the `COALESCE()` function to select data from the correct side of the join for use later on and in the select clause. This may also be the piece you were missing to make a CTE work.

There is probably also a solution that uses a ranking/windowing function (maybe not RANK itself, but something that category) along with the `PARTITION BY` clause. However, as those are fairly new to Sql Server I haven't used them enough personally to be comfortable writing an example solution for you without direct access to the data to play with, and it would still take me a little more time to get right than I can devote to this right now. Maybe this paragraph will motivate someone else to do that work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will see what I can come up with based on your suggestion.  Seems logical. If anyone can expand on Joel's answer and provide an example, that would be great!